# Не передаются параметры в метод

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Есть такой контроллер:

```
[Area("api")]
[Route("[area]/[controller]")]
public class ProgramsController : Controller
{       
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Turn(int id, int state)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return Content("It works!");
    }
}
```

Хочу, чтобы метод `Turn` обрабатывал запросы вида:

> *http://localhost/api/programs/turn?id=1&state=2*

Но при выполнении такого запроса параметры `id`и `state` не устанавливаются, хотя в `Request.Query` значения попадают.

В чем проблема?

---

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute( "areas", "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}");
        routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Programms}/{Action=Index}");
    });
}
```

Comment: @AK, Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Извините, но не воспроизводится. У вас ProgramsController находится в папке Areas/api? Я вот только что добавил Area через правый клик - добавить area - и всё работает.

Comment: @AK, Да, в такой же папке. И параметры нормально передаются в метод?

Comment: Ага. Давайте сравнивать, чем у нас различаются проекты.

Comment: @AK, Сейчас посмотрю более тщательно. Видимо я что-то упустил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась.

Не обратил внимание, что стояла конфигурация релиза. И в следствии оптимизации компилятором незадействованные переменные не инициализировались.

Достаточно было переключится в Debug и все стало нормально :)

Answer (score 1):

Не воспроизводится:

https://localhost:12345/api/Programs/Turn?id=1&state=2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Единственное отличие (на мой взгляд) - у меня route прописан был когда-то давно так, как предлагал скафоллдинг:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name : "areas",
        template : "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Хотя возможно ещё разный тип проекта: я-то воткнул в первый попавшийся проект под рукой (тип: Web Application Asp.net MVC), а у вас поди чистый API проект?

Update. Нет, дело не в типе проекта и не в маршрутах. Создал новое приложение и поэкспериментировал с разными route - дело не в них. Где-то у вас биндинг нестандартный.

> Сейчас посмотрю более тщательно. Видимо я что-то упустил.

Если зайдёте в тупик - попробуйте для начала создать новый пустой проект и в нём сделать area и такой простой контроллер, а потом уже сверять с основным проектом, чем они отличаются.